# Data size changes when training the model with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to train a CNN on the "Cifar10" data set. I import it and when I check the shape:

```
cifar10 = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0
y_train, y_test = y_train.flatten(), y_test.flatten()
print("x_train.shape:", x_train.shape)
print("y_train.shape", y_train.shape)
```

And what I get is:

```
x_train.shape: (50000, 32, 32, 3)
y_train.shape (50000,)
```

Which indicates my data has 50000 instances. However when training the model:

```
r = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=2)
```

The log shows:

```
Epoch 1/2
1563/1563 [==============================] - 7s 5ms/step - loss: 1.4601 - accuracy: 0.4819
Epoch 2/2
1563/1563 [==============================] - 7s 5ms/step - loss: 1.1266 - accuracy: 0.6025
```

Which is saying there are only 1563 instances. What could possibly cause this?

The complete notebook is available [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1hR5IlAM9mDNgto8PeM1MqdYatmiLJM3q)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see during the progress of your network is not the number of **instances** but rather the number of **batches**. By default, I guess your function divides your instances into batches and then proceeds by training them. I guess the default size for each batch is 32 therefore, you have 1563 number of total batches.

If you check the explanation for [fit function](https://keras.io/models/sequential/) you will see that the default `batch_size` = 32.

Comment: well, I'm following a tutorial, and in the video on the log, there is 50000. and this code is the sample from there. And also, I'm using the Model, not Sequential. And for this one, the batch_size is set to None. Any ideas?

Comment: this is new behavior, which also explains why this question is being posted daily